# How to read a compressed binary file as an array of floats

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I need to read a compressed unformatted binary file in as an array of floats. The only way that I have found to do this, is to use os to unzip, read it using np.fromfile, and then zip it up again.

```
os.system('gunzip filename.gz')
array = np.fromfile('filename','f4')
os.system('gzip filename')
```

However, this is not acceptable. Apart from being messy, I need to read files when I don't have write permission. I understand that np.fromfile can not directly read a compressed file. I have found people recommending that I use this:

```
f=gzip.GzipFile('filename')
file_content = f.read()
```

But this returns something like this: '\x00\x80\xe69\x00\x80\xd19\x00\x80'
instead of an array of floats. Does anyone know how to convert this output into an array of floats, or have a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've read the file content, you should be able to get an array using [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

f=gzip.GzipFile('filename')
file_content = f.read()
array = np.fromstring(file_content, dtype='f4')
```